# How to connect Salesforce to Microsoft Add in using oauth web server flow?

Tags: integration, oauth2, connected-apps, office-365

Hi I'm developing an add in to create template using word and on click of a button I want to upload the word file to Salesforce

But to achieve this I'm struck at a point how to connect Salesforce to office add in using web server flow

Thanks, I'm new to add in development

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific about where you're stuck. If you haven't already looked through it, the [official help pages on OAuth flows in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5) is a good place to start (well, trailhead's [Build Integrations using Connected Apps] trail might be better if you're completely new to OAuth).

Comment: I've created connected app in the salesforce and got the client credentials and secret key and everything but the issue is how do I use the code in the office add in to authenticate user and how to set up a call back url